# SQL Instance Error after adding the project to TFS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I was developing an MVC application with SQL 2014. I have used database first approach and generated edmx from my locally hosted SQL 2014 database. So the application was running fine with this local database and default instance.

But yesterday I added my project from my Visual Studio 2013 to TFS 2013(installed on our company server). The addition was successful but when I tried to run my solution it gave the instance error. The SQL instance used by server is:

> PEARLSERVER\SQLEXPRESS

Moreover when I tried to install SQL 2014 on our server, it neither asked for authentication type nor any instance. And the version mentioned after installation was of SQL 2012(Our server has already installed SQL2008, SQL2012). What could be the problem? What should I do? Should I add files to TFS from server or generate edmx again from server?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: @martpendle Studion gave the error **The Underlying provider failed on open** and when I tried to open the file it says **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: Now when I am trying to connect to a database from studio it is not showing any servers or even my own PC although all of them are connected. But before TFS it is showing them.

Comment: Can you connect to the DB via Management Studio? What does Sql Configuration Manager report the instances installed are?

Comment: Sounds like you have larger issues going on if you cant see you local instances now

Comment: Nope, When I am trying to connect to DB from Management Studio with a dot in server name.. it is giving the same error message

Comment: @martpendle can u tell why it is not asking for authentication or instance name when I installed SQL 2014 on server?

Comment: It really depends on how the instance was installed, if you installed it to use Windows auth then it might just be passing though your domain credentials, there are may variables at play here